# Remove all tags not matching p tag in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all tags that not match starting <p> tag.
I have sth like this:

```
 preg_replace("/<(?!p)>/", "", $html);
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: You can't parse HTML with a regular expression.  Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: You should seriously read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135448, it's hillarious and educative

Comment: Does that mean from your `$html` you also want to remove `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, `<title>` etc. tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), that's what it exists for.

```
$stripped = strip_tags( $str, '<p>' ); // Allow only paragraph tags
```

Demo Here: http://codepad.org/NEUEBWg7

Note that this function doesn't touch the attributes on the permitted tags. If you're filtering user input, be sure to consider that attributes like `onclick` and more could be abused to carry out some devious behavior.

Answer (score 3):

strip_tags is what you need.
Just do this:

```
$result=strip_tags($html,"<p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

At its most basic, use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove HTML:

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<p>');
```

Even better is [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)